# Select row from DataGrid and press Delete button ERROR: 42601

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGrid1.SelectedItem == null)
                return;
            DataRowView rowview = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
            NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=10.0.5.22;Port=5432;Database=TEST_DB;User Id=postgres;Password=test;");
            con.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("delete from Product where productcode="+rowview["productcode"]+"'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // here it is showing error as ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near ":"
            con.Close();
        }
```

When i select the row from **DataGrid** and press Delete button, it shows ERROR:

> 42601: syntax error at or near ":" (near to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Debug tip: when you build a command string and it gives an error, inspect the real resulting string - then you see the missing quote.

Comment: Does the postgresql connector support parameters? Then please use them to prevent sql injection (and this error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missed an apostrophe (') near *productcode='"*
Please try with this.

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGrid1.SelectedItem == null)
            return;
        DataRowView rowview = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
        NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=10.0.5.22;Port=5432;Database=TEST_DB;User Id=postgres;Password=test;");
        con.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("delete from Product where productcode='" + rowview["productcode"] + "'", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // here it is showing error as ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near ":"
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please select as accepted solution if this resolution solves your problem. Bye. :-)

Comment: Jineesh: Thank You.. but its deleting from the database . how to refresh the datagrid after i invoke with delete button

Comment: You have to once more access the data from the database and bind it to the DataGrid as you previously bind the data. Or just call the bind method once more.